# Setting up nested/child route in Angular 2 router

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Setting up some nested routing that should look like mypage/param1/1/param2/2 in the URL. The 1 is the first parameter, and the 2 is the second parameter. There should always be two parameters, otherwise there should be an error. This isn't working for me yet. Am I on the right track here?

```
   {
        path: 'param1/:param1',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'param2/:param2', component: SomeComponent },
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
  {
    path: 'param1/:param1',
    children: [
      { path: 'param2/:param2', component: SomeComponent },
    ]
  }
```

There's only one component that handles both variables. Errors will occur if you define a component for 'group/:groupID'.